# Distortion of the spherical gaussian error through the canonical embedding in Ring - LWE

Tags: ring-lwe

In the paper, "On Error Distributions in Ring-based LWE" by Castryck, Iliashenko and Vercauteren, page 3, It is shown that the distrotion to the spherical gaussian in Ring - LWE is caused by the inverse of the vandermonde matrix and the matrix of multiplication by f'(x). It is explicitly stated that the inverse of Vandermonde matrix B is converted into a real matrix by a "easy unitary transformation". Can anyone help me out in figuring how get such a unitary transformation that takes a complex matrix to a real one?

[image: Screenshot of the section in that paper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section you quote is from the introduction. The paper goes into more technical detail later. For example, equation 3.1 states (roughly) the same equation, and then states that:

$$B = U\Sigma$$

Where $\Sigma$ is the matrix of the canonical embedding, expressed relative to the basis $\{\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n\}$, and $U$ is the matrix (defined on page 5):

$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{s\times s} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}I_{t\times t} & \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}I_{t\times t}\\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}I_{t\times t} & \frac{-i}{\sqrt 2}I_{t\times t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$U$ is unitary, and known to be an isomorphism $(H, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_H)\cong (\mathbb{R}^n, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle)$, where $\langle x,y\cdot\rangle_H = \sum_i x_i\overline{y_i}$ is the *Hermitian* inner product, and $H$ is a certain conjugation-invariant subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that contains the image of the canonical embedding.
This is all discussed on page 5.

Comment: Thank you! That helped